# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'. Con Angular 5.0.3 - Ionic 3.19.1

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

Tengo un error que sucede solamente cuando ejecuto el comando "ionic serve", y en el navegador me tira el siguente mensaje

Typescript Error
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

src/providers/concurso/concurso.ts

```
    return concursos.map((concurso) => new Concurso(concurso));
  })
```

Les adjunto el codigo tal como tengo:

```js
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Concurso} from '../../models/concurso';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class ConcursoProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

 }

  public getAllConcursos(): Observable<Concurso[]>{
     return  this.http.get('/concursosj')
      .map(concursos => {
        
        return concursos.map((concurso) => new Concurso(concurso));
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
      });

  }
```

Comment: tengo mi duda con esta linea `return concursos.map((concurso) => new Concurso(concurso));` no tienes que hacer antes de esto algo como :  `let misConcursos = concursos.json() misConcursos .map((concurso) => new Concurso(concurso));` recibes un [response](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) de datos de angular mas tus valores del consumo

Comment: Tienes que llamar `http.get` con un parametro generico, por ejemplo `http.get<any[]>('/concursosj')`. Solamente tienes que asegurar que el dato que recibies si tiene ese tipo o te va a saltar un Runtime Error.

Comment: @JackNavaRow , el backend ya me trae en formato json

Comment: pero estas llamando a via HTTP debes hacerlo por eso no me cuadra, haz un `console.log(concursos.json() )` deberia de devolver tu json

Comment: @Tao funciono como me dicias, ahora me salta error en el catch, Dice: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Concurso[]>) => ObservableInput<{}>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: @DiegoxMotta el error significa que el metodo que pasas a `catch` tiene que devolver un `ObservableInput`. No se por qué lo requiere. rxjs 5 tiene una nueva manera de usar operadores, quizá te funciona mejor: `import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'` y `http.get<any[]>(...).pipe(map(...), catchError(...))`